# Shannon-Fano code as max-heap in python

Tags: python, algorithm, encoding, heap, binary-tree

I have a min-heap code for Huffman coding which you can see here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Python

I'm trying to make a max-heap Shannon-Fano code which is similar to min-heap.

Here is a code:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import heapq, math

def _heappop_max(heap):
"""Maxheap version of a heappop."""
lastelt = heap.pop()    # raises appropriate IndexError if heap is empty
if heap:
    returnitem = heap[0]
    heap[0] = lastelt
    heapq._siftup_max(heap, 0)
    return returnitem
return lastelt

def _heappush_max(heap, item):
    """Push item onto heap, maintaining the heap invariant."""
    heap.append(item)
    heapq._siftdown_max(heap, 0, len(heap)-1)

def sf_encode(symb2freq):
heap = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in symb2freq.items()]
heapq._heapify_max(heap)
while len(heap) > 1:
    lo = _heappop_max(heap)
    hi = _heappop_max(heap)
    for pair in lo[1:]:
        pair[1] = '0' + pair[1]
    for pair in hi[1:]:
        pair[1] = '1' + pair[1]
    _heappush_max(heap, [lo[0] + hi[0]] + lo[1:] + hi[1:])
print heap
return sorted(_heappop_max(heap)[1:], key=lambda p: (len(p[1]), p))
```

But i've got output like this:

```
Symbol  Weight  Shannon-Fano Code
!   1   1
3   1   01
:   1   001
J   1   0001
V   1   00001
z   1   000001
E   3   0000001
L   3   00000001
P   3   000000001
N   4   0000000001
O   4   00000000001
```

Am I right using heapq to implement Shannon-Fano coding? The problem in this string:

```
_heappush_max(heap, [lo[0] + hi[0]] + lo[1:] + hi[1:])
```

and I don't understand how to fix it.

Expect output similar to Huffman encoding

```
Symbol  Weight  Huffman Code
    2875    01
a   744 1001
e   1129    1110
h   606 0000
i   610 0001
n   617 0010
o   668 1000
t   842 1100
d   358 10100
l   326 00110
```

Added:

Well, I've tried to do this without heapq, but have unstopable recursion:

```
def sf_encode(iA, iB, maxP):
global tupleList, total_sf
global mid
maxP = maxP/float(2)
sumP = 0    
for i in range(iA, iB):
    tup = tupleList[i]
    if sumP < maxP or i == iA: # top group
        sumP += tup[1]/float(total_sf)
        tupleList[i] = (tup[0], tup[1], tup[2] + '0')
        mid = i           
    else: # bottom group
        tupleList[i] = (tup[0], tup[1], tup[2] + '1')
print tupleList
if mid - 1 > iA:
    sf_encode(iA, mid - 1, maxP)
if iB - mid > 0:
    sf_encode(mid, iB, maxP)
return tupleList
```

Comment: What do you expect your output to be?

Comment: @ScottHunter, I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

In Shannon-Fano coding you need the following [steps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding):

> A Shannon–Fano tree is built according to a specification designed to
>   define an effective code table. The actual algorithm is simple:
>
> 1. For a given list of symbols, develop a corresponding list of
>      probabilities or frequency counts so that each symbol’s relative
>      frequency of occurrence is known.
> 2. Sort the lists of symbols according
>      to frequency, with the most frequently occurring symbols at the left
>      and the least common at the right.
> 3. Divide the list into two parts,
>      with the total frequency counts of the left part being as close to the
>      total of the right as possible.
> 4. The left part of the list is assigned
>      the binary digit 0, and the right part is assigned the digit 1. This
>      means that the codes for the symbols in the first part will all start
>      with 0, and the codes in the second part will all start with 1.
> 5. Recursively apply the steps 3 and 4 to each of the two halves,
>      subdividing groups and adding bits to the codes until each symbol has
>      become a corresponding code leaf on the tree.

So you will need code to sort (your input appears already sorted so you may be able to skip this), plus a recursive function that chooses the best partition and then recurses on the first and second halves of the list.

Once the list is sorted, the order of the elements never changes so there is no need to use heapq to do this style of encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I know this algorithm, but I'm trying to do this with heapq lib. I've tried to do this without it, but output codes were like in uniform encoding.